# Unit Testing a custom attribute class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes, mocking

I have a `custom attribute` that is just used to mark a member (no `constructor`, no `properties`):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute { }
```

How would I unit test this? And, to clarify... I know the 'what', but not the 'how'

I assume there is a way to unit test it to ensure the proper `AttributeUsage` is in place? So how could I do this? Every time I create a mock class and try to add the attribute to the wrong thing it won't let me compile, so how can I create a bad mock class to test?

Comment: @Kornelije: I fixed his title for him. If you click on his name, he must've left the title from his last question in there. :)

Comment: Yea, sorry about that. Firefox had my same question and title already in the entry form for me. I forgot to change the title.

Comment: @michael, You need 100% code coverage? :-)

Comment: @polishchuk: Shouldn't we all aim for 100% code coverage?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You would not create a mock class to test this. Instead, you would simply test the attribute class itself to see if it has the proper `AttributeUsageAttribute` attribute properties. *whew, what a mouthful*

```
[TestMethod]
public void Is_Attribute_Multiple_False()
{
    var attributes = (IList<AttributeUsageAttribute>)typeof(MyCustomAttribute).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AttributeUsageAttribute), false);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, attributes.Count);

    var attribute = attributes[0];
    Assert.IsFalse(attribute.AllowMultiple);
}

// Etc.
```